# Special character at the start and end of Hebrew text showing wrong direction

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, w3c

If I type any special character at the start and end of Hebrew text in an input field the value of the input field direction showing wrong. Can anyone have any idea how I can resolve this?

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input id="test" type="text" v-model="text" />
    <div class="render">{{ text }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      text: "hello",
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#test {
  direction: rtl;
}
</style>
```

I get this type of view

[image]